# Android: Handle App Link Verification failure at install time

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, applinks, digital-assets-links

I added app link feature with autoVerify set for my app following [link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html)

On testing the app, it worked in the begining. Then after reinstalling the build, not working.

On debugging what I found is the response time for my .well-known/assetlinks.json file is > 1sec.

which gives timeout error on test-url https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://example.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

{
  "maxAge": "599.999999353s",
  "debugString": "********************* ERRORS *********************\n* Error: deadline_exceeded: Timeout occurred while fetching Web statements from https://example.com./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to 'https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json') using download from the web (ID 1).\n********************* INFO MESSAGES *********************\n* Info: No statements were found that match your query\n"
}

Looks like because of this timeout, verification is failing.

I would like to know whether app/system retry verification at any point later if verification failed on install (may be because of connection issue or temporary website down)?

Comment: From This link: https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-app-linking-how-it-works/ , What I understand is it will attempt link verification only once per install. If verification fails on install, it will have normal behaviour. Next verification happens only if we update the app.

Comment: Was it a fault at your server end? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Android M does not automatically reattempt verification if it fails due to timeout or connectivity issues. As you found [in this guide](https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-app-linking-how-it-works/) the next attempt will occur on app update or re-install.

Comment: what is this to do with Android M? isnt this also failing on google verification tool?

Comment: Any news on Android 12 to somehow reverify the host? I still have the same issue.